# Error using horzcat - textscan - import to matlab

Tags: matlab, csv

I have large table in csv file I would like to import to matlab.
my data look like this

```
2015-08-19 13:07:06,2015-08-20 00:00:00,0,0,2,2,97,74089906202417,96140046618,117409555595550,2,0,1
```

I tried to use:

```
dataArray = textscan(fileID, '%{yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss}D%{yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss}D%u%u%u%u%d%u64%u64%u64%u%u64%u', 'Delimiter', ',', 'WhiteSpace', '',  'ReturnOnError',  false);
fclose(fileID);
a = [dataArray{1:end}];
clearvars
```

But it dose not work due to mismatch in data types, this error

> Error using horzcat
>   Dimensions of matrices being concatenated are not consistent.
>   Error in a = [dataArray{1:end}];

Now can anyone tell me how can I import this data??? (the datetime columns are very important to me to import properly)

Note: I tried all the following format but still I have the error.

> - 'datenum(%D)datenum(%D)%u%u%u%u%d%u64%u64%u64%u%u64%u';
> - ' %s%s%u%u%u%u%d%u64%u64%u64%u%u64%u';
> - ' %f64 %f64 %f64%f64%f64%f64%f64%f64%f64%f64%f64%f64%f64'
> - ' %s %s %f64%f64%f64%f64%f64%f64%f64%f64%f64%f64%f64'

Comment: Can you give some samples of the data in `dataArray`? So what does `dataArray{1}`, `dataArray{2}`... etc output?

Answer (score 1):

Corrected code is provided below. In the code, you don't have to store to an array if not needed. You can access each element in `dataArray` like this `dataArray{2}(5)`, In this case you will get the `second date and time` in the `5th line` in csv file.

I used `%s` instead of `%u64` for `74089906202417,96140046618,117409555595550` because

> 74089906202417 will fit in %u64
>
> 96140046618 will fit in %u64
>
> 117409555595550 will not fit in 117409555595550

Considering the possibility that the other two may also wont fit in other lines of csv file, I used `%s` for all three of them. You can change it as per your data.

```
fileID = fopen('data.csv');
dataArray = textscan(fileID,'%s %s %u %u %u %u %d %s %s %s %u %u %u','Delimiter',',');
fclose(fileID);

% Storing to array
dateTime1 = cell2mat(dataArray{1});
dateTime2 = cell2mat(dataArray{2});
uinteger1=dataArray{3};
uinteger2=dataArray{4};
uinteger3=dataArray{5};
uinteger4=dataArray{6};
integer1=dataArray{7};
string1=cell2mat(dataArray{8});
string2=cell2mat(dataArray{9});
string3=cell2mat(dataArray{10});
uinteger5=dataArray{11};
uinteger6=dataArray{12};
uinteger7=dataArray{13};
```